# How to i create a dummy column whilst using an if statement?

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a datsaset which shows tax paid by a number of different local authorities.

I want to create a dummy column, so that if I state specific local authorities in an if statement, if they match it returns a value of 1, if not it returns a value of 0.

I have tried:

```r
mutate_if(tax_data, localauthority %in% c('Exeter', 'Glasgow', 'Oxford'), funs(dummy==1))
mutate_if(tax_data, localauthority != c('Exeter', 'Glasgow', 'Oxford'), funs(dummy==0))
```

Can anyone provide any help on how i can use an if statement whilst creating a dummy column to satisfy this condition?

Comment: try case_when , it has easy syntax

Comment: `mutate(tax_data, dummy = as.numeric(localauthority %in% c('Exeter', 'Glasgow', 'Oxford'))`

Comment: For a clearer look at `ifelse()` statements for dummy variables, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461445/how-to-create-a-dummy-variable-in-r-using-ifelse-command)

Comment: `mutate_` are used to select columns to be "mutated" on

Comment: Try `mutate(tax_data, dummy = ifelse(localauthority %in% c('Exeter', 'Glasgow', 'Oxford'), 1, 0)`


Moreover, it will easier to answer your question if you provide a reproducible example. see [here] ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for how to make a great R reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

mutate and case_when:

```
# `%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)

tax_data%>% mutate(dummy = case_when(
                  localauthority %in% c('Exeter', 'Glasgow', 'Oxford')~ 1,
                  localauthority %notin% c('Exeter', 'Glasgow', 'Oxford')~0
                                      )
```

or use ifelse:

```
tax_data%>% mutate(dummy = ifelse(localauthority %in% c('Exeter', 'Glasgow', 'Oxford'),1,0))
```